# coding a blackjack game using dictionary-python

Tags: python

I used an alternative way to develop a Blackjack game, but I noticed that the first 2 dealer cards for both user and computer are always the same. is there something I didn`t do right? I need help on tnis.

```
import random
from replit import clear

deck={"ace": 11,
      "jack":10,
      "queen": 10,
      "king":10,
      "one": 1,
      "Two":2,
      "Three": 3,
      "four": 4,
      "five": 5,
      "six": 6,
      "seven": 7,
      "eight": 8,
      "nine": 9,}

def computer_draw():
  # for i in range(1):
  computerchoice= random.choice(list(deck.keys()))
  computerlist.append(deck[computerchoice])
  return sum(computerlist)


def user_draw():
  # for i in range(1):
  mychoice=random.choice(list(deck.keys()))
  mychoicelist.append(deck[mychoice])
  return sum(mychoicelist)


def calculate_score(deck):
  if sum(deck) == 21 and len(deck) == 2:
    return 0
  if 11 in deck and sum(deck) > 21:
    deck.remove(11)
    deck.append(1)
  return sum(deck)

  
def cal(userscore, computerscore):
  if userscore > 21 and computerscore < 21:
    return("you lose ")
  elif userscore < 21 and computerscore > 21:
    return("you win ")
  elif userscore==0:
    return("you win, Blackjack!")
  elif computerscore==0:
    return("computer wins, Blackjack!")
  elif userscore==computerscore:
    return("It`s a draw!")
  elif userscore==21:
    return("you win!")
  elif computerscore==21:
    return("you lose!")
  elif computerscore > userscore:
    return("You lose ")
  else:
    return("you win ")


mychoicelist= []
computerlist= []
def play():

  is_game_over=False
  for i in range(1):
    mychoicelist.append(user_draw())
    computerlist.append(computer_draw())
    
  while not is_game_over:
    userscore=calculate_score(mychoicelist)
    computerscore=calculate_score(computerlist)
    print(f"User has {mychoicelist} with score of {userscore}")
    print(f"computer has {computerlist[0]}")
    if userscore==0 or computerscore==0 or userscore>21: 
      is_game_over= True
    else:
      decision=input("do you want to draw, Y or N? ").lower()
      if decision=="y":
        user_draw()
      else:
        is_game_over= True
        # print(f"user has {mychoicelist} with scores {userscore}")
        
  while computerscore != 0 and computerscore < 17:
    computer_draw()
    # computerlist.append(computer_draw())
    computerscore= calculate_score(computerlist)
  print(f"computer {computerlist} with score of {computerscore}")
  print(f"user {mychoicelist} with score of {userscore}")
  print(cal(userscore, computerscore))

while input("do you what to play blackjack game y or n: ")== "y":
  del mychoicelist[:]
  del computerlist[:]
  clear()
  play()
```

this is where my problem is but don`t know how to correct it to stop outputing 2 same card numbers.

```
for i in range(1):
    mychoicelist.append(user_draw())
    computerlist.append(computer_draw())
```

Comment: From a quick run it looks like your code is OK, but you have some indentation errors. I'll post it in an answer in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

There are various approached towards your code dependent upon the outcome you desire. Firstly, if you add `return` keyword within your `for` loop then it will run only once.

Approach 1: **random.choices()**

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html
As per their docs, you can generate various random outputs without repeating. In your case,

```
def user_draw(count): # Where count is your iteration for loop not needed
  mychoice=random.choices(list(deck.keys()),k=count)
  mychoicelist.extend([deck[choice] for choice in mychoice]) # List Indexing and extend()
  return sum(mychoicelist)
```

Similarly,

```
def computer_draw(count):
  computerchoice= random.choices(list(deck.keys()),k=count)
  computerlist.extend([deck[choice] for choice in computerchoice])
  return sum(computerlist)
```

Approach 2: **Basic Python**

Suppose, I have a list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. Now if I select randomly one number I could get any of them with a 0.25 probability. However, if I want to select two the probability would change *(only if you don't replace)*. Similarly you can remove the already outputted items from your list and re-append them if you want.

**Method Without Appending Again:**

```
def user_draw(count):
  deckList = list(deck.keys())
  for i in range(count):
    mychoice=random.choice(deckList)
    mychoicelist.append(deck[mychoice])
    deckList.remove(mychoice) # Removes the Item From List
  return sum(mychoicelist)
```

**Method With Re-Appending:**

```
def user_draw(count):
  deckList = list(deck.keys())
  reappendList = []
  for i in range(count):
    mychoice=random.choice(deckList)
    mychoicelist.append(deck[mychoice])
    deckList.remove(mychoice) # Removes the Item From List
    reappendList.append(mychoice) # Make a note of the removed items
  deckList.extend(reappendList)
  return sum(mychoicelist)
```

However, this method is not recommended because you are anyways going to re-define the `deckList` variable everytime the function is called and you aren't hindering the main `deck` dictionary. Though, it could be used for other approached!

I would recommend going with Approach 1: **random.choices()** since it is more efficient!

Comment: Didn't look into your indentation. I simply wrote the code within stackoverflow. You could replace the `  ` with `tabs`.